# Android: How do I change the rating an indicator rating bar?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have an indicator rating bar:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:rating="2.5"
    android:numStars="5"/>
```

You can see that the xml tells the rating bar to reflect 2.5 stars currently.

At a click of a button, I want it to reflect 5 stars instead, so I wrote this code:

```
indicatorRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        indicatorRatingBar.setIsIndicator(false);
        indicatorRatingBar.setRating(5);
        indicatorRatingBar.setIsIndicator(true);
    }
});
```

**The rating bar does not update at all**. I don't know if it is because it is an indicator rating bar?

How can I get this to work properly with the rating bar set at the indicator style?

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the answer through trial and error. I just needed to call invalidate on the view as it has changed and it doesn't invalidate itself automatically.

```
indicatorRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        indicatorRatingBar.setRating(5);
        indicatorRatingBar.invalidate();
        indicatorRatingBar.setIsIndicator(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
indicatorRatingBar.setRating(5.0f);
```

Comment: Nope. This will make no difference.